# scanf_s removing I char from buffer

Tags: c, string, scanf, visual-studio-2019

I'm writing a program to convert from Roman numeral to Arabic and vice-versa. The program was working perfectly for both until I added a way for the program to check if the input is a number or string.

Now everything still works except it neglects the first `I` in every string on the scanner(`scanf_s`). That does not happen to any subsequent`I` or any other letter.

ie.

II reads I into romanString

IV reads V into romanString

XX reads XX into romanString

XIX reads XIX into romanString

Comment: "That does not happen to any subsequent Is or any other letter." --> Did you try [N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Zero)?  I suspect the same trouble will occur due to `NAN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I` is part of `Infinity` and `scanf_s("%f",...` consumes the `I` but fails to find the rest and returns 0.

`scanf()` and family are a poor way to parse variant formats.  Better to read a *line* with `fgets()` and then parse the *string*.

or if required to use `scanf_s()` ...

```
    char romanString[100];
    float arabicNumber=0;

    printf("Enter roman or arabic number:");
    scanf_s("%99s", romanString, 99);  // should be scanf_s("%99s", romanString, 100);
    if (sscanf_s(romanString, "%f", &arabicNumber) == 1)
    {
        printf("Roman numerals: ");
        arabicToRoman(arabicNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Arabic numerals: ");
        romanToArabic(romanString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes encounter these kind of problems, try adding before all the scanf_s the command fflush(stdin) (or fpurge(stdin) if you code with Xcode).

"The _fpurge() function requests that any pending data in the stream be discarded." In this case, the data pending on your keyboard.